# PHP, MySQL, One page Website

Tags: php, mysql

at my work we have a system my boss developed where we have one page (index.php), and the different pages are stored within a database instead of different page files.

I was wondering if anyone knew any good tutorials on how to do this? Or if any of you would be able to help me in code it up?

Comment: Can't you just use an existing content management system?

Comment: extremely vague, and if youre asking questions like this at your job don't you think you are a bit unqualified?

Comment: I would prefer using something that is coded by me, and I am using this because I am creating my first Web app for learning purposes, so it is something I want to learn to do.

Comment: @Keiron but what is it exactly that you want to learn to do? Can't you just look at how the system your boss created works? I'm confused.

Comment: @nick I'm mostly a front-end developer, my boss is slowly getting me more and more into PHP etc but I still no very little.

Comment: @Pekka Were very busy at work at the minute, so there is never any time for him to explain the code to me, plus he has been ill for the past couple of weeks.

Comment: @Keiron Lowe: Then you should just start by reading a tutorial on PHP/MySQL. You can find tons of them on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+mysql+tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tutorial walks you through how to accomplish what you described. However, I would suggest you just skim over it and write something from scratch which uses better coding methods.

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/content-management-system-cms-using-php-and-mysql.aspx

Comment: Cheers that seems to be exactly what I want, and I want to develop something from scratch anyway so Thanks :)

Comment: As I see it, maybe your boss didn't develop any system, and he is using just a free CMS system... :P just for the record.

Answer (score 4):

***That's wrong***

- `Database` is database
- `Business logic` is business logic
- `Front end` is front end.

That can work for website with less than 15 pages, or static pages, but will be harder to maintain.

You can have what goes inside the `body` tag in your database in a `table` with the title and some `javascript` tags for the `header`.

Anyhow if what you want is all pages be accessed through the `index.php`, i will recommend to store the other pages as `.php` files too, and with some `switch`/`if`(whatever) to control the page you will call.

something like:

```
$pageid = $_GET["pageid"];
switch ($pageid) {
    case 0:
        include('contact.php');
        break;
    case 1:
        include('home.php');
        break;
    case 2:
        include('whoweare.php');
        break;
}
```

and the url will be something like

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?pageid=1
```

or

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/?pageid=1
```

---

### References

I will also recommend some links that can help you through this **learning season**:

- [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)
- [Building Dynamic Web Pages with PHP](http://www.techiwarehouse.com/engine/d3bf2317/Building-Dynamic-Web-Pages-with-PHP)
- [First Web Page](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472431/PHP-Tutorial-First-Page.htm)

Comment: +1 this is true. The concept of having code in the database (if that is what is at hand) sounds awfully wrong.